# jquery efficient way to select tablerow data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with multiple rows of the same pattern:

```
<tr role="row" class="even">
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="valj4"></td>
  <td>Generell grupp</td>
  <td><a href="/Home/DeviceDetails?uuid=2b9fe569-dd6a-403c-b973-fd577acf12b5">IKT Ipad11-    Mirko</a></td>
  <td>Grundinställningar</td>
</tr>
```

Each row has a checkbox with unique ID, what would be the most efficient way to get a list of UUIDs for the rows with a checked checkbox. I would like to use jQuery.

Comment: Can you please share with us your attempts thus far?

Comment: You could also add a class on the fields and iterate through them using a foreach, and then checking the current checkbox id to manipulate it the way you want

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I suspect it's not about efficiency, but about "how to do it?"

Comment: did you tried any thing ?

Comment: I use a foreach right now, but i think some kind of jquery selector is better?

Comment: It is not necessarily better; but jQuery selector is more *expressive*, to a person who knows how to read it, as it compresses lines and lines of code in a easy compact string. However, since it requires capabilities that are beyond the standard selectors, jQuery will still need to iterate over nodes, thus you are not necessarily doing anything computationally worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var texts = [];
  $('tr td:has(input:checkbox:checked) ~ td > a').each(function(i, e) {
    texts.push($(e).attr('href'));
  });
  $('#result').html(texts.join('<br/>'));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="valj4" checked>
    </td>
    <td>Generell grupp</td>
    <td><a href="/Home/DeviceDetails?uuid=2b9fe569-dd6a-403c-b973-fd577acf12b5">IKT Ipad11-    Mirko (...5)</a>
    </td>
    <td>Grundinställningar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="valj4">
    </td>
    <td>Generell grupp</td>
    <td><a href="/Home/DeviceDetails?uuid=2b9fe569-dd6a-403c-b973-fd577acf12b6">IKT Ipad11-    Mirko (...6)</a>
    </td>
    <td>Grundinställningar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="valj4" checked>
    </td>
    <td>Generell grupp</td>
    <td><a href="/Home/DeviceDetails?uuid=2b9fe569-dd6a-403c-b973-fd577acf12b7">IKT Ipad11-    Mirko (...7)</a>
    </td>
    <td>Grundinställningar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"/>
```

Getting the UUID is then an easy exercise in string chopping.

Comment: @Lix: Yeah, that was quickest to write and show results. Replaced with nicer.

Comment: very nice selector to get the link +1 :)

Comment: Note: `input` is redundant with the `:checked` selector. `:checkbox:checked` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your table has an id and it's "#table-id":

```
$("#table-id").find(":checked")
```

would get you all the checked checkboxes and radio boxes.

```
$("#table-id").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

would get you all the checked checkboxes.

```
var ids = "";
$("#table-id").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    ids += $(this).attr("id") + ",";
});
```

would give you a comma seperated list containing the ids of checked checkboxes in the table.

and the UUIDS list:

```
var UUIDs = "";
$("#table-id").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).closest("tr").find("td > a").first().attr("href");
    var UUID = href.split('?')[1];
    UUIDS += UUID + ",";
});
```

Comment: the `:checkbox` pseudo selector is simpler than using `input[type='checkbox']`, so you could simply have `$('#table-id :checkbox:checked)` as your selector. `:checkbox` has been available since version 1.0 of jQuery

Comment: Yes, I couldn't remember that because I usually use the attribute selector type.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following

```
var ids = [];
$("#table input:checkbox:checked").each(function () {
    var uuid = getParameter($(this).closest('tr').find('a').eq(0).attr('href'))
    ids.push(uuid);
});

function getParameter(url) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]uuid=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

where `#table` is the id of your table

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/edbx39f0/3)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list of UUIDs.

```
var listOfUUIDs = [];
```

Get the checked input, go up to grandparent (the tr), then find the a inside it.

Go through the list of a's, adding UUIDs to the list.

```
$("tr input[checked=checked]").parent().parent().find("td a").each(function(){ 
    listOfUUIDs.push(
        $(this).prop('href').substr(indexOf("uuid=") + 5)
    )
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer briefly for the benefit for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('#formId').find('tr[class=even]').each(function () {

```
var rowId = "";

this.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

    if(this.checked) {
        rowId = "row" + $(this).val();
    }

});
$(this).attr('id', rowId);
```

});

Answer (score -1):

This should give you what you need.

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    var $this   = $(this), 
        input   = $this.find('input'),
        result  = '';

    if ( input.is(':checked') ) {
        var uuid    = $this.find('a').attr('href').replace(/^\/Home\/DeviceDetails\?uuid=/g, ""),
            result  = result + index + '. ' + input.attr('id') + ' has the uuid: ' + uuid + '<br />';
    }

    $('#result').html(result);
});
```

Comment: Your `replace()` command is far to specific to the example HTML to be used as a complete solution.

Comment: this would be a quick solution if the link is the same every time, if the link is different instead of replace use something like this http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-parse-url/ , but think this should be enough

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).change(function() {
 if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
  }
 });
```

Comment: I need the UUID not the ID of checkbox